# How to output all rows of KTable to Kafka Topic using KSQL

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams, ksqldb

I am new to Ksql and trying aggregation, have created a Kstream & a Ktable which looks like this

kstream...

```
 CREATE STREAM test
  (id BIGINT,
   type VARCHAR,
   sales BIGINT
  WITH (KAFKA_TOPIC='test1',
        VALUE_FORMAT='JSON');
```

ktable...

```
CREATE TABLE test_total AS
SELECT ID,
       SUM(SALES) AS TOTAL_SALES
FROM test
GROUP BY ID
EMIT CHANGES;
```

Published these values into Kafka test1 topic

```
{"id": 1, "type": "test","sales": 200}
{"id": 1, "type": "test","sales": 300}
```

When I use the Kafka console consumer I only see the output as

> {"TOTAL_SALES":200}
> {"TOTAL_SALES":500}

How can I see the id also printed into the Kafka topic? Do I have to create some kind of view out of the table?

Answer (score 1):

In your console-consumer command add

```
--property print.key=true
```

If you already using ksql, you can also SELECT from your created TABLE

Comment: SELECT works fine, end goal is to put the output of Ktable into some DB. So I wanted to see what it looks like in Kafka Consumer. Adding --property print adds weird character ""

Comment: added KEY_FORMAT='JSON' in Ktable definition, now I can see the integer 1 or 2 but without the ID. It shows like this - 1 {"TOTAL_SALES":600}. My Kafka connect also crashes with this format. Looks like Something missing on KTable definition and nothing to do with Kafka consumer console print?

Comment: You can use SMT HoistField , please post new question with examples and the error you are experiencing

Comment: If my answer was useful to you, you should at least +1 it, thanks

Comment: I was giving Kafka connect as an example, my original question still stays, If I don't see properly formatted json on Kafka console consumer for sure it will not work  on Kafka connect. I don't know what I am missing in the Ktable definition

Comment: I can't +1 due to low reputation, can only accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

In ksqlDB, primitive types are serialized as primitive types into the topic.

Cf https://docs.ksqldb.io/en/latest/reference/serialization/

There is not much you can do about it atm.